# AWS service for video post processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a local program that inputs a video, uses a tensorflow model to do object classification, and then does a bunch of processing on the objects. I want to get this running in AWS, but there is a dizzying array of AWS services. My desired flow is:

video gets uploaded to s3 --> do classification and processing on each frame of said video --> store results in s3.

I've used Lambda for similar work, but this program relies on 2 different models and its overall size is ~800 MB.

My original thought is to run an ec2 instance that can be triggered when 3 receives a video. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can consider creating a docker image containing your code, dependencies, and the model. Then, you can push it to ECR and create a task definition and fargate cluster. When the task definition is ready, you can set up a cloudwatch event, which will be triggered upon s3 upload, and as a target, you can select fargate resources that were created at the beginning.

There's a tutorial with a similar case available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. I would configure S3 to send new object notifications to an SQS queue. Then you can have your EC2 instance poll the queue for pending tasks. I would probably go with ECS + Fargate for this, but EC2 also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amazon Elemental to split the video file, and distribute the parts to different lambdas, so you can scale it, and process it in parallel.